# Parse html NSString

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, regex

I have `HTML` with a lot of strings in this format :

```
<li><a href="#track_info_page?artist=text&title=text">
```

And I want to get an `array` of this *string* with this `Regex` :

```
NSString *regex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<li><a href=\"#track_info_page?(.*?)\">"];

NSArray * arr = [html componentsMatchedByRegex:regex capture:1L];
```

But the `NSArray` is always empty.
Any idea what can be the problem ?

Comment: That first `?` needs to be escaped and I think the second should be outside of the `()` group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this regex:

```
NSString *regex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<li><a href=\"#track_info_page\\?(.*?)\">"];
```

The first `?` shall be escaped; `page?` will match `pag` and `page` but not `page?`.

Also keep in mind that [regexs are not a suitable means to full html parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), so if you plan to do complex things, at some point you will stumble in some blocking point.

Comment: @downvoter why? I mean.. I also wouldn't use regex but it will work

Comment: I tried your code and i get array but in every string i get this error: `<invalid>) [0] = <error: expected ']' error: 1 errors parsing expression>` . Any idea why?

Comment: @MTA: could you fix the problem? The regex is working for me...

Comment: Yep the debugger is not showing the array but in the log is saw it. Thanks!!

Comment: The `?` in `(.*?)` is required to make the pattern *non-greedy*. Otherwise it would match everything up to the last `">` found in the input string.

Comment: @MartinR: thanks, you are right. I had completely missed that, although it's a must. Edited my answer...